# 2D histogram with 3 arrays (x,y and value) in python

Tags: python, histogram

I have 3 arrays (positions x,y and value of this dots (F). The F array has value from negative numbers to positive (-10,10, for example). I did 2d histogram, but, as you can see, the background is colored in yellow. I need background with the lowest color.
The code I use

```
h=np.histogram2d(x,y, bins=80, weights = F)
plt.figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=200)
plt.axes(facecolor = 'grey')
plt.imshow(h[0], extent=[-5, 5, -5, 5], origin = "lower", cmap='hot', 
interpolation="gaussian")
plt.colorbar()
```

[what i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dN5RX.png)

[what i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ps4g7.png)

Maybe I do everything wrong? because I must have maximum value of F array in the center area
Please help!)

Comment: Why not just use plt.2dhist? For the effect with gray background you just have to set vmin/vmax to your desired threshold.

Comment: plt.figure(figsize=(2, 2), dpi=200)
h=plt.hist2d(x, y, bins=np.linspace(-5, 5, 50),cmap='hot', weights = F, vmin=-10, vmax=0)
plt.colorbar(label='log(F)')
Anyway, it thinks that background is the brightest colors